# Getting Thread EXC_BAD_ACCESS on BerkeleyDB sample code

Tags: c, malloc

I'm writing my very first C program and I was really doing well. The application talks to RESTful server. All was good until I decided to use an embedded database(libdb) for storage. I got this code below that was part of my entire program. My problem is it keeps on crashing on this line:

my_archive->db_home_dir = DEFAULT_HOMEDIR;

I thought I was running out of stack so I malloc'd all my lengthy variables but the problem was still occuring so I decided to separate this libdb part into a new code, but the problem still remains.

Any idea what has gone wrong here?

P.S. I'm doing all the coding in Xcode and stepping through each line after debug breakpoint right after main() doesn't help me a bit. Always ends up on the same error line. Or perhaps I just don't know what I'm doing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "db.h"

#define DEFAULT_HOMEDIR "/Users/mark/Documents/bdb/"
#define URLSDB "urls"


typedef struct archive_dbs {
    DB *URLS_dbp;
    char *db_home_dir;
    char *URLS_db_name;
} ARCHIVE_DBS;


void initialize_archivedbs(ARCHIVE_DBS *my_archive)
{
    my_archive->db_home_dir = DEFAULT_HOMEDIR; //CRASHES HERE: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x1000061da)
    my_archive->URLS_dbp = NULL;
    my_archive->URLS_db_name = NULL;
}

void set_db_filenames(ARCHIVE_DBS *my_archive)
{
    size_t size;
    size = strlen(my_archive->db_home_dir) + strlen(URLSDB) + 1;
    my_archive->URLS_db_name = malloc(size);
    snprintf(my_archive->URLS_db_name, size, "%s%s", my_archive->db_home_dir, URLSDB);
}


int open_database(DB **dbpp, const char *file_name, const char *program_name, FILE *error_file_pointer)
{
    DB *dbp;
    u_int32_t open_flags;
    int ret;

    ret = db_create(&dbp, NULL, 0);
    if (ret != 0) {
        fprintf(error_file_pointer, "%s: %s\n", program_name,
                db_strerror(ret));
        return(ret);
    }
    *dbpp = dbp;
    dbp->set_errfile(dbp, error_file_pointer);
    dbp->set_errpfx(dbp, program_name);
    open_flags = DB_CREATE;
    ret = dbp->open(dbp,
                NULL,
                file_name,
                NULL,
                DB_BTREE,
                open_flags,
                0);
    if (ret != 0) {
        dbp->err(dbp, ret, "Database '%s' open failed.", file_name);
        return(ret);
    }

    return (0);
}

int databases_setup(ARCHIVE_DBS *my_archive, const char *program_name, FILE *error_file_pointer)
{
    int ret;
    ret = open_database(&(my_archive->URLS_dbp), my_archive->URLS_db_name, program_name, error_file_pointer);
    if (ret != 0)
        return (ret);
    printf("databases opened successfully\n");
    return (0);
}

int databases_close(ARCHIVE_DBS *my_archive)
{
    int ret;
    if (my_archive->URLS_dbp != NULL) {
        ret = my_archive->URLS_dbp->close(my_archive->URLS_dbp, 0);
        if (ret != 0)
            fprintf(stderr, "URLS database close failed: %s\n",
                    db_strerror(ret));
    }

    printf("databases closed.\n");
    return (0);
}


int main(void){


    ARCHIVE_DBS *archivedbs;
    initialize_archivedbs(archivedbs);
    set_db_filenames(archivedbs);
    databases_setup(archivedbs, "urlfetcher", NULL);
    open_database(&archivedbs->URLS_dbp, "URLS.db", "urlfetcher",
              NULL);
    databases_close(archivedbs);




    }
```

Comment: When you call, `initialize_archivedbs(archivedbs);` the pointer is uninitialized.

Comment: Thanks. I thought I could ignore that warning from xcode since my program was running fine until i came to a point where i wanted to declare a new variable and was getting segfault. I thought malloc'ing alone would solve it, turned out it was indeed the culprit. The beauty of C programming I guess. You have to know what you are doing everytime. I have to admit, that was not part of the berkeleydb example. They were my own code. I thought I'd call those functions that way. But i do have a question though. Assigning NULL to the structure pointer doesn't work but assgning = malloc(sizeof... does?

Comment: Why is your `archivedbs` a pointer in the first place?

Comment: Hi melpomene,. I was just following the example in the berkeleydb documentation. The function prototype says: "void initialize_stockdbs(STOCK_DBS *); So in my case, I just renamed STOCK_DBS typedef to ARCHIVE_DBS since my program isn't about stock inventories..
"